# How to add values to POSTGRES IN Clause along with subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple query and require simple solution in PostgreSQL. Query is

```
SELECT distinct(id)
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3) 
OR id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_names WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND is_valid = true)
```

Note:

1. e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4 are valid ids.
2. Subquery should return ids from only 1, 2, 3

Lets say 3 is valid so it should return 1, 2, 3 and not 4

But seems it is not working, I missed some basics but can I get the answer.

Comment: Is `id` unique?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
   OR id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE is_valid = true)
```

Even better:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
   OR is_valid = true
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I need subquery for some condition but why "OR" instead of "AND"

Comment: Why `OR`? Because `id IN (val1, val2, ...)` means `id = val1 OR id = val2 OR ...`